# Accessing historical app usage database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

What is the best way to access the app usage database on Android, without using the API?

In particular, I would like to make a local copy of the database behind this API:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStats.html

Answer (score 0):

There's no *best* way, other than the API. You may or may not receive the permission to access this data. On [this page](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html) it says:

> NOTE: This API requires the permission
>   android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS, which is a system-level
>   permission and will not be granted to third-party apps. However,
>   declaring the permission implies intention to use the API and the user
>   of the device can grant permission through the Settings application.

It reads as though you might get the permission if you declare it and the user grants it... or you might not, as it will not be granted to third-party apps.

Comment: Perhaps an important point is that I am not trying to build a product from it. Rather, i am trying to get a copy of the raw data for personal data mining

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't decide on a case-by-case basis, so unless you root your device and poke around, you won't be able to get what you want.